# NDBI Chart - No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

Ideally, I'd like to be running a yearly chart observing NDBI of my selected geometry. I believe I may be missing part of the code for that, and I am unsure how to go about it. I'm running into the above error with the code:

```
var l8_2015 = l8.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2020-12-31');

var image = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(  
{
 collection: l8_2015,
 asFloat: true 
});

Map.addLayer(image.clip(table), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'landsat 8');

var ndbi = image.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');

var ndbiParams = {
  min: -1, 
  max: 1, 
  palette: ['cyan', 'red']
};



var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11', 'NDBI']; 

Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(table), ndbiParams, 'ndbi');

var ndbi16Trends = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:ndbi,
  regions:table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  band: 'NDBI',
  scale: 30
```

I believe I need to set system:time_start, but I'm not sure where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create time series chart from a **single image**, you need to have Image collection for that.
`ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite` takes Image collection as an input and returns **an** Image as an output.

Instead of doing this, you can create a `map` function to evaluate NDBI band for each and every image in your image collection then create a trend chart from that.